# Сложный placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Есть инпут с подложкой-плейсхолдером (внутри плейсхолдера предусмотрены картинки, поэтому обычный способ тут не вариант). Я написал скрипт который при клике на плейсхолдер делает его невидимым и появляется focus на инпуте. Но как вернуть плейсхолдер при клике на левые области не знаю.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.background-layer').click(function() {
    $('.input-field').addClass('fade');
    $('.input-field').focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
}
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.background-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.input-field.fade {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="input-field">
  <div class="background-layer">placeholder</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.background-layer').click(function() {
    $('.input-field').addClass('fade');
    $('.input-field').focus();
  });
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".background-layer");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('.input-field').removeClass('fade');
        $('.input-field').blur();
        container.css({'opacity': 0});
      
      if($('.input-field').val().length === 0){
        container.css({'opacity': 1});
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
}
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.background-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.input-field.fade {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="input-field">
  <div class="background-layer">placeholder</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ Елена, есть еще один момент - если заполнить поле и нажать на стороннюю область, плейсхолдер перекрывает введенные данные. Это можно исправить?

Comment: Дополнила ответ. `$('.input-field').val(' ');`

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо, я плохо формулирую свои соображения. Я имел в виду чтобы заполненное поле при клике на стороннюю область оставалось таковым, без наложения плейсхолдера. То-есть если поле valid - плейсхолдер при потере инпутом фокуса не отображается..

Comment: Так? Добавила еще правку)

Comment: про валидность, это уже Вы добавляйте проверку и если валидно, то `$(".background-layer").fadeOut();` если нет, то можно `$('.input-field').val(' ');` например так.

Comment: Пооочти)) Сейчас, после введения данных в форму и потери фокуса, отредактировать введенную информацию невозможно..

Comment: А сейчас?)))))))))))))))

Comment: а сейчас чёртов плейсхолдер после потери фокуса не появляется вообще)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46394/discussion-between-elena-semenchenko-and-).

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.background-layer').click(function() {
    $('.input-field').addClass('fade');
    $('.input-field').focus();
  });
  $('.input-field').focusout(function() {
    $('.input-field').removeClass('fade');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
}
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.background-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.input-field.fade {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="input-field" >
  <div class="background-layer">placeholder</div>
</div>
```